# WinAPI functions in Free Pascal Lazarus 1.0.2 (FPC 2.6.0)

Tags: winapi, freepascal, lazarus

I'm trying to compile a Delphi project in [Free Pascal](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free_Pascal) [Lazarus](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lazarus_%28IDE%29) and get compiler errors, because several WinAPI functions (`CreateNamedPipe`, `GetLastError`, `OutputDebugString`) can't be found.

The `uses` clause of the file in question looks like this:

```
uses
  SysUtils,
  LCLIntf, LCLType, LMessages;
```

Which units should I add to the `uses` clause in order to fix the aforementioned compiler errors?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need the Unit **Windows** for the WinAPI.

```
uses SysUtils, LCLIntf, LCLType, LMessages, Windows;
```

Comment: is the coverage pretty solid and complete? (of the winapi - as compares to Delphi 7 and below)